# Counting the values of a map

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, counting, treemap

The following map contains data of the form:

```
1946-01-12;13:00:00;0.3;G
1946-01-12;18:00:00;-2.8;Y
1946-01-13;07:00:00;-6.2;G
1946-01-13;13:00:00;-4.7;G
```

The dates are the keys.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class WeatherDataHandler {
    private NavigableMap<LocalDate, List<Weather>> weatherData =
            new TreeMap<>();
    
    public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
        List<String> fileData =
                Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
        for (String str : fileData) {
            List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(parsed.get(0));
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(parsed.get(1));
            double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
            String quality = parsed.get(3);
            Weather weather =
                    new Weather(date, time, temperature, quality);
            
            List<Weather> entries;
            entries = new ArrayList<Weather>();
            if (weatherData.get(date) == null) {
                entries.add(weather);
                weatherData.put(date, entries);
            } else {
                entries = weatherData.get(date);
                entries.add(weather);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private List<String> parseData(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split(";"));
    }
}
```

Now, I want to implement a method that counts the number of entries of every key, or in other words, the number of times every date occur in the list. It shall return all dates between two dates (that is user input) and the number of values of every key. I started with the following code

```
/**
 * Search for missing values between the two dates (inclusive) assuming there
 * should be 24 measurement values for each day (once every hour). Result is
 * sorted by date.
 */
public Map<LocalDate, Integer> missingValues(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {

    Map<LocalDate, Integer> counts = weatherData.subMap(dateFrom , dateTo)
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .filter(p -> p.getValue()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
    }
}
```

but I am having troubles with the filter and collectors method. How can I finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by date of `Weather` class and `Collectors.counting()` to count the size of every group.

```
Map<LocalDate, Long> counts = weatherData.subMap(dateFrom ,dateTo)
                                         .values()
                                         .stream()
                                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getDate(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you effectively need is to group by the date as the key element of the map. In the value, you want how many times each key has occurred.

For this, you will have to use `Collectors.groupingBy` while collecting the map. and for the value, it would be simply `Collectors.counting()`. Please check the code snippet below for more detail:

```
Map<LocalDate, Long> countMap = weatherData
                                .subMap(dateFrom ,dateTo)
                                .values()
                                .stream()
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getDate(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using streams to simplify your code you may also want to do the following.

Instead of doing

```
    List<Weather> entries;
    entries = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    if (weatherData.get(date) == null) {
         entries.add(weather);
         weatherData.put(date, entries);
    } else {
        entries = weatherData.get(date);
        entries.add(weather);
    }
```

You can just do

```
     weatherData.computeIfAbsent(date, k->new ArrayList<>()).add(weather);
```

It says that if the key `date` is not there, put in a new `ArrayList` as the value.  In any event, return the `value`.  Since the value is the `list` that was either just entered or already there, you can then simply add the `weather` instance to the list.

The compiler already knows the type of list since it derived that from your `NavigableMap` instance.

If you want to check it out first, try this simple example.

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
System.out.println(map);
map.computeIfAbsent(10, k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(20);
System.out.println(map);
map.computeIfAbsent(10, k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(30);
System.out.println(map);
```

[computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) has been available since Java 1.8